# Finding the interval of values of an unknown element such that a square matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm looking for a way to determine which values of $c \in \mathbb{R}$ make the matrix $A$ positive semidefinite:

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & c \\
c & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm looking for a way to determine which values of c∈R make the matrix
> A positive semidefinite:

By definition, A matrix is called positive semidefinite if it is symmetric and all its eigenvalues are non-negative. Hence

```
Clear["Global`*"]
mat = {{1, c}, {c, 1}}
If[SymmetricMatrixQ[mat],
 eigv = Eigenvalues[mat];
 Reduce[eigv[[1]] >=  0 && eigv[[2]] >= 0, c]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So any value between -1 and 1 will do. The above code ofcourse assumes the matrix is 2 by 2, but it can easily be made more general.

Comment: Hello @Nasser thank you very much for your helpful answer.

Comment: Congrats on 100K.

Answer (score 6):

Start with the characteristic polynomial.

```
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[{{1, c}, {c, 1}}, t]

(* Out[142]= 1 - c^2 - 2 t + t^2 *)
```

There are two important things to check.
(i) Where do roots cross the y axis?
(ii) Where might roots be complex-valued?

For (i) we just solve for `c` under the assumption that`t==0`

```
Solve[cp == 0 && t == 0, {c, t}]

(* Out[143]= {{c -> -1, t -> 0}, {c -> 1, t -> 0}} *)
```

This splits the real line for `c` into three regions abd simply plugging in a value in each region will show that both solutions are nonnegative in the finite part.

For (ii) We check where the discriminant with respect to `t` vanishes. This will give conditions on `c`.

```
Discriminant[cp, t]

(* Out[144]= 4 c^2 *)
```

So it only vanishes at the origin. We already know that on neither side do we have complex valued roots in `t`. So there are no further restrictions.

An advantage to this approach is that it extends to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix, and simplify it under the assumptions you gave:

```
Simplify[CholeskyDecomposition[{{1, c}, {c, 1}}], c ∈ Reals]
   {{1, c}, {0, Sqrt[1 - c^2]}}
```

you can immediately read off the condition that `Sqrt[1 - c^2] >= 0` for positive-semidefiniteness. Thus,

```
Reduce[%[[-1, -1]] >= 0, c, Reals]
   -1 <= c <= 1
```

which matches Nasser's answer.